# Entity Framework delete constraints

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my EDM I have two entities `Contact` and `Address`. In my `Address` entity I have `contactID` foreign key. How can I add constraint that prevents me from deleting a contact if that contact is still being used in some `Address` entity?

Thanks

Comment: You really should have such a constraint in the underlying database. If you do, then EF will automagically pick that up and enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining your database and generating the EF model from there then add a constraint to your database using syntax like:

```
 ALTER TABLE [Address] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Contact] FOREIGN KEY([ContactID]) REFERENCES [Contact] ([ID])
```

Then add the tables back to your EF designer and it should recognize the association and add the necessary properties required to support the constraint.